# ¿Como se pueden guardar imágenes en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base64

Tengo la necesiad de guardar muchas imagenes en mi servidor y relacionarlas con registros especificos de algunas tablas. Por facilidad en la administración de dichas imagenes con respecto a los registros seria increible que se pudiera guardar en un campo de la tabla. Recientemente descubri base64 con el cual paso dicha cadena a cierto framework(pdfmake) y me permite insertar una imagen a un pdf.

Para convertir la imagen a base64 con javascript uso:

```
function convertFileToDataURLviaFileReader(url, callback) {
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onload = function() {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
          callback(reader.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
   };
   xhr.open('GET', url);
   xhr.responseType = 'blob';
   xhr.send();
}
```

Despues lo guardaria en Mysql y cuando necesite la imagen tomo dicho campo y lo pasaria de base64 a img. Alguien ve algun inconveniente o tiene una mejor forma de guardar las imagenes en Mysql?

Comment: Generalmente eso no se hace, la imagen se guarda directamente en el servidor y en la base de datos solo una referencia del ruta para llegar a dicha imagen.

Comment: Pero debe haber alguna forma de relacionar las imagenes con algun registro de la tabla.

Comment: Sí, con el nombre de la imagen y un campo adhoc en la base de datos. Y el nombre de la imgen puede ser su hash.

Comment: Pero que pasa si borro primero el registro y por error no borro la imagen. Esta imagen quedaría como basura en el servidor.

Comment: Para eso se suele hacer que el mismo proceso que borra el registro, sea el que borre la imagen. Pero como solución alternativa, es hacer un cron, que recorra el directorio de las imágenes por la noche y compruebe si esta dado de alta en la base de datos

Comment: Estás usando PHP en el backend?

Comment: @jufrfa hice una prueba de concepto usando PHP en el layer de interacción con la BBDD y podría ponerla en la respuesta, pero necesito que me confirmes que usas PHP, para no hacer el ridículo respondiendo algo que no es lo que preguntaste.

Comment: Claro estoy usando PHP.

Comment: Cualquier opción es bienvenida.